# Filtering a list by preferred sort

Tags: sql, sql-server

This might have an obvious solution, but I can't remember what to call this at the moment.

Let's say you have a table like this:

```
Member | ID     | Type
------ | ------ | ------
100    | 1      | A
100    | 2      | B
101    | 3      | A
102    | 4      | A
103    | 5      | B
104    | 6      | B
104    | 7      | A
104    | 8      | A
```

If a member has an A I want to return all rows with an A for that member.
If a member does not have an A then I want to return all rows with a B for that member.

I realize I could write a solution using NOT EXISTS, but I was wondering if there is a more generic solution (in case of multiple categories).  Basically I want to filter by whether a category exists, in a preferred order.

In this example the result would return:

```
Member | ID     | Type
------ | ------ | ------
100    | 1      | A
101    | 3      | A
102    | 4      | A
103    | 5      | B
104    | 7      | A
104    | 8      | A
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Member int,ID int,[Type] varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(100 , 1 , 'A'),
(100 , 2 , 'B'),
(101 , 3 , 'A'),
(102 , 4 , 'A'),
(103 , 5 , 'B'),
(104 , 6 , 'B'),
(104 , 7 , 'A'),
(104 , 8 , 'A')

Select Member,ID,Type
 From (
         Select *
               ,RN = Dense_Rank() over (Partition By Member Order by Type)
          From  @YourTable
      ) A
 Where RN=1
```

Returns

```
Member  ID  Type
100     1   A
101     3   A
102     4   A
103     5   B
104     7   A
104     8   A
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick.  I hadn't heard of dense_rank() before.  Thank you!

Comment: @JJ32 The window functions are our friends.  Well worth the time to get comfortable with them.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
     ;WITH tb(Member,ID ,Type)AS
     (
        SELECT  100,1,'A' UNION
        SELECT  100,2,'B' UNION
        SELECT  101,3,'A' UNION
        SELECT  102,4,'A' UNION
        SELECT  103,5,'B' UNION
        SELECT  104,6,'B' UNION
        SELECT  104,7,'A' UNION
        SELECT  104,8,'A'
    )
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *,MAX(CASE WHEN type='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )OVER(PARTITION BY tb.Member) HasA  FROM tb
     ) AS t WHERE (t.HasA=1 AND t.Type='A') OR t.HasA=0
```

```
Member      ID          Type HasA
----------- ----------- ---- -----------
100         1           A    1
101         3           A    1
102         4           A    1
103         5           B    0
104         7           A    1
104         8           A    1
```

Comment: Yes, that works.  But I don't see how this would apply to cases where there are, say, a dozen categories.  How can I make this into a more generic solution?

Comment: Can you give more detail about  your requirment ?